# Использование функции SetWindowExtEx и SetViewPortExtEx

Tags: delphi

Перед мной поставлена задача создать окно предварительного просмотра (точнее поставили).

И так, что я имею:
На форме поставлены

```
  ScrollBox : TScrollBox;
  PaintBox : TPaintBox;    
  PageSetupDialog: TPageSetupDialog;
  {И кнопки, и.т.д.}
  ...   
  PaintBox.Parent = ScrollBox;
```

При изменение размера ScrollBox и масштаба (имеется ComboBox) калькулируется размер и положение PaintBox. 
Здесь проблем нет!. Алгоритм отлично работает при любом размера масштабирования (от 10% до 350%)

И вот здесь я не могу продвигаться дальше:
При рисования на поверхности компонента PaintBox необходимо изменить значения протяженности холста (как можно сделать так, что бы Zoom работал).

Вот параметры принтера:

```
LOGPIXELSX = 600;
LOGPIXELSY = 600;
HORZSIZE = 210;
VERTSIZE = 297;
HORZRES = 4961;
VERTRES = 7016;
PHYSICALWIDTH = 4961;
PHYSICALHEIGHT = 7016;
PHYSICALOFFSETX = 0;
PHYSICALOFFSETY = 0;
```

При 80% масштабирование у компонента PainBox вот такие параметры:

```
  Left = 175;
  Top = 8;
  Width = 499;
  Height = 707;
```

А ScrollBox:

```
  Left = 0;
  Top = 27;
  Width = 853;
  Height = 727;
```

На эти функции какие данные из картинки надо поставить?

```
SetWindowExtEx(PaintBox.Canvas.Handle,  ?, ?, nil);
SetViewPortExtEx(PaintBox.Canvas.Handle, ?, ?, nil);
SetViewportOrgEx(PaintBox.Canvas.Handle, ?, ?, nil);
```

[image: http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualfile.aspx?id=18184933]

Эти 3 API функции не могу понят, и прошу от Вас помощь разобраться.
Везде про этих функции объяснили ссылаясь физические координаты и логические координаты.
А нигде конкретно не написано, что себя представляют физические координаты и логические координаты, и еще системные координаты. Вот эти термины меня отвлекают. И поэтому не могу поставить параметров показанные в картинке.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался и отлично понял координаты компьютерной графики!
В этом мне помогли:

- ***Win32 API. Эффективная разработка приложений. Щупак Ю.А. (Питер, 2007 г.)***;
- ***Графический интерфейс GDI в Microsoft Windows Александр Фролов, Григорий Фролов***
- *MSDN*

И так:

```
Function TForm1.PrinterCoordX(X: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := round(600 / 25.4 * X);  // 600 - LOGPIXELSX
end;

Function TForm1.PrinterCoordY(Y: Integer): Integer;
begin
  PrinterCoordY := round(600 / 25.4 * Y);  // 600 - LOGPIXELSY
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBoxPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  FontPerInch : Integer;
begin
  with Sender as TPaintBox do
  begin
    SetMapMode(Canvas.Handle, MM_ANISOTROPIC); 

    // отображаемую часть геометрической модели (А4 бумага)  на поверхности устройства (Дисплея)
    SetWindowExtEx(Canvas.Handle, {printer PHYSICALWIDTH = 4961}  Printer.PageWidth, {printer PHYSICALHEIGHT = 7016}    Printer.PageHeight, nil);

   // размер геометрической модели  (А4 бумага) на поверхности устройства (Дисплея)
   SetViewPortExtEx(Canvas.Handle, Width , Height , nil); //PaintBox : Width = 499, Height = 707  

   // расположение геометрической модели  (А4 бумага) на поверхности устройства (Дисплея)
   SetViewportOrgEx(Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, nil);  

   FontPerInch := GetDeviceCaps(Printer.Handle, LOGPIXELSX);
   CheckToLess(FontPerInch, GetDeviceCaps(Printer.Handle, LOGPIXELSY));
   Canvas.Font.PixelsPerInch := FontPerInch;

   Canvas.TextOut(TForm1.PrinterCoordX(25), TForm1.PrinterCoordY(25), 'Hello World');
  end;  
end;
```

Этот текст печатается с отступом 25 мм от левого края и 25 мм от верха при любом разрешении принтера.